# python function that return all initial segments of a list

Tags: python

I am trying to produce a function that take as input a list of string and returns all the initial segments of that list.

i.e the output should be:

```
([[], ['k'], ['k', 'i'], ['k', 'i', 'm'], ['k',    'i', 'm', 'i']])
```

I have done the following but it is not correct because I get number instead of characters.

```
def funv(k):
    return [[i for i in range(i)] for i in range(len(k))]
```

Can anyone tell me what can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
[list(k[:i]) for i in range(1, len(k)+1)]
```

Comment: Much prettier (and correct as his version has a bug that drops the last character). Technically you want `range(0, len(k)+1)` since he expected an empty list on the front, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what you are doing, but it sounds like you are just missing one small thing.  Instead of returning `i` in your inner list comprehension, you want to return `k[i]`.  `i` is the position where `k[i]` would be the character at position `i`.

```
def funv(k):
    return [[k[i] for i in range(i)] for i in range(len(k))]
```

Comment: thanx you for your help :)